# Error in Summary.factor ‘min’ not meaningful for factors!! How can I eliminate this error?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 30 row and 850 column. Some column of this data has "nan" and "inf" value. For instant, I create a sample of my data frame like this

```html
test<-data.frame(a=c("inf",1,"inf"),b=c("nan",3,"nan"))
row.names(test)<-c("w1","w2",w)
```

I have changed inf and nan to zero with this code

```html
na_code<-c("nan","inf")

     test<-as.data.frame(lapply(test, function(x) {
    +   levels(x)[levels(x) %in% na_code] <- 0
    x }) )
```

so I have a data type of data frame.Is it correct?
when I want to normalize my data with this function

```html
normalize<-function(x){
  return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

```html
norm_test<-lapply(test, normalize)
```

I faced this error

```html
 Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 1L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

I try this code

```html
norm_test<-lapply(as.list(test), normalize)
```

I faced the same error!!!
How can I fix this ٍError?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `as.numeric` in `lapply` like this:

```
test<-as.data.frame(lapply(test, function(x) {
     levels(x)[levels(x) %in% na_code] <- 0
  as.numeric(x) }))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it was a great attempt at solving the problem---but I wish to introduce you to some shortcuts.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
test %<>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>% 
  mutate_all(~if_else(is.infinite(.x) | is.nan(.x), 0, .x))
```

This will first of all produce the effect of turning infinite values and NaNs to zero. Then, since we have converted factors to characters and characters back to numeric, we can now apply `normalize` function again.